# How is the "e" in "clerk" pronounced differently from "terse", "term" and "jerk"?

Tags: pronunciation

*clerk*, *terse*, *term*, *jerk*: every one of these words contains an "e" and it is pronounced as "e".

However, I have seen "clerk" being treated differently from the other three words: the "e" was underlined in a different way from that of the others. Can you explain why?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, but in the UK, _clerk_ is normally pronounced klɑːk (to rhyme with bark).

Comment: It's pronounced the same

Comment: @Andrew MacFie Unhelpful. It's pronounced the same way the others are _in some countries_. Not usually so in the one the language is named after.

Comment: Wow thank you!That's totally helpful!I took note to edit but I had just delete other 2 questions which weren't in need, thank you for clarify my question!I can't find it anywhere in any books of the social stores!

Comment: Thank you, but in my topic it must be different, so I am finding it!

Comment: I have heard Americans pronounce the word cla k and clark.  But, I have not heard that pronunciation recently. I imagine electronic media has homogenized the pronunciation to mostly clerk in the United States.

Comment: What do you mean by "underlined in a different way"? What does underlining have to do with pronunciation?